# Comparing Char which holds hex values C++

Tags: c++, compare, hex

in C++ I have two chars holding hex values e.g.:

```
char t = 0x4;
char q = 0x4;
```

How would i compare if the two values held in the char are the same?? I tried

```
if (t == q) // should give me true
```

but no, any help, thanks!

Comment: Wait, something's wrong here. That should, and does execute if branch of the conditional. We need more context. Your "a & b" answer is not correct - that will be "true" for any overlapping bits in the representation of a and b

Comment: That should work. Why do you think it does not?

Answer (score 11):

A char is just an 8-bit integer.   It doesn't matter if you initialized it with hex or decimal literal, in either case the value of the char will be the same afterwards.

So:

```
char t = 0x4;
char q = 0x4;
if(t == q)
{
 //They are the same
}
```

It is equivalent to:

```
char t = 4;
char q = 4;
if(t == q)
{
 //They are the same
}
```

You mentioned that the above is not true, but you must have an error in your code or t and q must not be the same.

**What you suggested...**

> if (t == q) // should give me true
>   but no, any help, thanks!

**is not correct.  Why?**

t & q does a bitwise compare, returning a value where both aligned bits are 1.

The term "if(t&q)" would return true as long as any of the bits of t and q are in common.

so if t = 3 which is in binary 00000011 and q = 1 which is in binary 00000001 then (t&q) would return true even know they are not equal.

Answer (score -8):

Ah, I found the solution:

```
if (t & q)
```

Comment: That should be

    if ( t && q ) 

Your statement, (t & q), does a bit-wise comparison.  Granted, this may be what you want.

Comment: In any case, this isn't what he asked. If t and q are initialized as presented, then t==q certainly gives true - atleast with my compiler.

Comment: Martin the problem with it is mostly that it works for too many values.  Example t= 3 and q = 1.

Comment: BobS, while I think the downvoting has been a bit excessive here, I think you should have just edited your question and added this info to the end of it.